# Pandas: How to create a "master" record when de-duping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Example pandas dataframe below -

```
ID  ADDRESS       COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  
1   123 FRONT ST  2017  
1   123 FRONT ST           2016
1   123 FRONT ST                     2018
2   324 2nd st    2008
2   324 2nd st              2014
```

My goal is to de-dupe the dataframe above but for "COLUMN1 - COLUMN3" I want to keep the values if the field is not null in the final result. Pretty much looking for a way to make a "master" record for each ID (Address and ID will always be the same).

The target result is this -

```
ID  ADDRESS       COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  
1   123 FRONT ST  2017      2016    2018
2   324 2nd st    2008      2014
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for `df.groupby(['ID', 'ADDRESS']).max()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('ID').first()
Out[156]: 
       ADDRESS  COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3
ID                                       
1   123FRONTST   2017.0   2016.0   2018.0
2     3242ndst   2008.0   2014.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) or
[`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) or [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) or [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) or [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','ADDRESS'], as_index=False).max()
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID       ADDRESS  COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3
0   1  123 FRONT ST   2017.0   2016.0   2018.0
1   2    324 2nd st   2008.0   2014.0      NaN
```

If not necessary processing later is possible convert to `object`:

```
df = df.groupby(['ID','ADDRESS'], as_index=False).max().astype(object)
print (df)
  ID       ADDRESS COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
0  1  123 FRONT ST    2017    2016    2018
1  2    324 2nd st    2008    2014     NaN
```